# symbol navigator show the h or m file

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, when I click a method in the symbol navigator, sometimes it load the method definition in the .h file, while sometimes it load the m file, how is it decided?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, here is what I found anyway, if the method is defined in .h file, it always load h file, if a method is not defined in h file but in m file, it still shows up in the list and when you click it, xcode load the m file. that's smart...

Comment: Not so smart if you straight want to go to the implementation